# Spotipy: how do I find linked tracks in Spotify using the Python API

Tags: python, search, spotify, spotipy

My playlist and recently played have different track IDs sometimes.  Example my playlist has:

```
reload_id = '0wnRRFzKLDdI5jjvDP3lZV'
recent_id = '5vOGEMTcx7ns5CtQ5y41lo'

(Pdb) reload_name
'One Moment in Time - Remastered'
(Pdb) reload_artist
'Whitney Houston'

(Pdb) recent_name
'One Moment in Time'
(Pdb) recent_artist
'Whitney Houston'
```

I included the raw JSON for each track at the bottom.

I assume that my playlist track (reload) is not playable due to market or some other reason,  even thought that attribute is True for both.

If I search my the artist (same for both tracks) and recent name I get these tracks which is missing the reload track id.

```
(Pdb) search_q
'artist:Whitney Houston track:One Moment in Time'
results = sp.search(q=search_q, limit=50, type='track')
(Pdb) c
5IDUGTWbntYwO9SNmhuSWf One Moment in Time  Whitney Houston
3cxjdKOZAlZO1steLpP8dN One Moment in Time  Whitney Houston
5vOGEMTcx7ns5CtQ5y41lo One Moment in Time  Whitney Houston
16RzAKm2SLaNhMdqHaImSm One Moment In Time  Karaoke - Whitney Houston
5DuvpjG95Qg574Ba8MoB4D One Moment in Time - Acoustic Cover  Whitney Houston
```

If I just search for

```
Pdb) search_q
'Whitney Houston One Moment in Time - Remastered'
```

I get 50 or more results that are all over the place.   I'm trying to find a way to correlate the two tracks.

**I removed my raw JSON here as it kept getting flagged as spam.**

I have tried setting my market and pulled each track id and searched based on artist and title but cannot find any results that tie the two together.

Comment: I don't under stand what is your problem? "cannot find any results that tie the two together." which item and which item tie together?

Comment: I am getting my recently played tracks and trying to remove those from a playlist.  Sometimes the song that played is a different track id than what is in my playlist.  I'm trying to find the correct matching track.  I'm assuming the track in my playlist is not playable for some reason and spotify is playing an alternate (linked) track.   I'm trying to take the played track and match it with the track that is in my playlist.

Comment: your search query 'artist:Whitney Houston track:One Moment in Time' perfectly work.  I think your question title is already addressed  by yourself. Your deleted playlist id may be a cache problem. But no one can reproduce your situation.

Comment: My search only returned 5vOGEMTcx7ns5CtQ5y41lo,  not 0wnRRFzKLDdI5jjvDP3lZV.

Comment: From the "spotify.com"'s UI search with "artist:Whitney Houston track:One Moment in Time" , the result are "5IDUGTWbntYwO9SNmhuSWf", "3cxjdKOZAlZO1steLpP8dN", "5vOGEMTcx7ns5CtQ5y41lo" and "5DuvpjG95Qg574Ba8MoB4D". 4 songs are matched your API search result. There are no " 0wnRRFzKLDdI5jjvDP3lZV" why you think return " 0wnRRFzKLDdI5jjvDP3lZV"?